# Preparing RGB files for print

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, rgb, digital-printing

The printing company that I use prefer all files to be supplied in RGB. The only problem for me is accidentally picking a colour that is too bright.

Is there an easy way around this? I recently heard about the gamut warning in Photoshop when picking colours so maybe I could use that.

Alternatively I could convert all images and swatches to CMYK, and then back to RGB... but that feels a little messy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photoshop colour picker with only colours within the printable gamut?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81612/photoshop-colour-picker-with-only-colours-within-the-printable-gamut) - the accepted answer should do what you want.

Comment: Another option is to set `View > Proof Setup` correctly for CMYK output, then choose `View > Proof Colors` this will *display* files as if they are CMYK, even though they are still RGB.

Comment: Have you asked them for a printer profile? They may not even be using 'straight' CMYK. High-end 'art' inkjets are 8-colour & can get a lot closer to sRGB than a standard separation process. I send a lot of photographic work to be done on canvases from sRGB files & I've stopped worrying the returned work won't be almost indistinguishable or at least within acceptable tolerance.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I'd say @Scott's recommendation works for me nicely — although unfortunately it doesnt seem to work in Illustrator, but I can work-around that

Comment: ermm.. yeah I just assumed Photoshop for RGB.. dunno why `:)` I'd guess because RGB in Ai, for me, is strictly web stuff.

Comment: Illustrator *does* work, just a bit differently. Choose `View > Proof Setup > Customize...` and choose your CMYK profile of choice and click OK. This turns on the proof view by itself, you can turn off again with `View > Proof Colors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing comments...

One option with **Photoshop** is to set `View > Proof Setup` correctly for CMYK output, then choose `View > Proof Colors` this will *display* files as if they are CMYK, even though they are still RGB. It's does *not* alter the files, it merely changes how things are displayed.

One can also turn on the [`Gamut Warning`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81612/photoshop-colour-picker-with-only-colours-within-the-printable-gamut) in the **View Menu** in Photoshop.

---

For **Illustrator** (from @Vincent)

Illustrator works a bit differently. Choose `View > Proof Setup > Customize...` and choose your CMYK profile of choice and click `OK`. This turns on the proof view automatically, you can turn off the proof view with `View > Proof Colors`.